Doppler effect in the case of a moving hydrogen atom

An electron in a hydrogen atom moving at speed $v \ll c$ goes from a state $m$ to $n$, emitting a photon of frequency of $\nu$. In a different experiment, the hydrogen atom is kept at rest and the electron goes from a state $m$ to $n$, emitting a photon frequency $\nu_0$. Prove that $\nu = \nu_0(1+v/c)$.

MY DOUBT: Our sir solved this problem using conservation of energy and momentum in the non relativistic limit and, even though this result looks a lot like Doppler effect, my sir said it is not the Doppler effect, so shouldn't we also include the Doppler effect of light in non relativistic limit, which gives $\nu = \nu_0(1+2v/c)$, which means that the Doppler effect can't be neglected?
Futher doubt: I also saw Harvard lecture notes in which Doppler spectroscopy was discussed; there, also, they didn't include a factor of $2$, so is this expression just the Doppler effect? And if it's not, then why are we not using Doppler effect here? A non-Bohr model explanation would also work. I just want to know what is happening.


This sounds like a conceptual non-homework problem to me. You mention the Mossbauer effect. You might expect a different frequency if an atom emits a photon and recoils vs an atom in a lattice emits a photon and the entire lattice recoils a tiny bit.

I think I got your point but just for clarification: isn't the Doppler effect $\nu = \sqrt{1+\beta \over 1-\beta}\nu_0$? And Doppler effect is not isotropic, so it depends if the wave is coming or going away. Is it here the same?

@Ruffolo yes I mentioning the same doppler effect and in this case if what our sir derived was mossbauer effect then shouldn't we also include the Doppler effect?

By Doppler effect, we know that
$$
\nu = \nu_0 \sqrt{1+\beta \over 1-\beta}
$$
where $\beta = v/c$. For $\beta <<1$,
$$
\nu = \nu_0 \sqrt{1 + 2{\beta \over 1-\beta}} \approx \nu_0(1+\beta)
$$
as you showed. Now, this is not Mossbauer effect, since, as you said, it's possible to obtain it by simple energy and momentum conservation applied to a free hydrogen atom. Mossbauer effect is observed by atoms bounded in a solid, manifested by a resonant absorption and emission of gamma rays, without recoil of the nucleus. As I know, there are no Mossbauer effect for gases, let alone a single atom.
Frequency change due to moving atoms
As you can see, Doppler effect displace the frequency of radiation emitted and absorbed by atoms, no matter if they are in a solid or gas. When we study the emission of radiation by nuclear process of the atom, the frequencies are so high (X ray, gamma, etc) that the atoms suffer recoil in the emission process (we can show it by conservation of energy). This recoil implies that the atom, initially at rest, aquire some velocity in opposite direction of the emitted radiation, relative to any stationary detector. By Doppler effect, the detected radiation are observed in a displaced frequency.
Mossbauer showed that in some solids, however, such displacement doesn't happen, due to collective action of the lattice in the atom. Thanks to that, we can observe the correct frequency of nuclear emission.
I would suggest you the Nobel lecture of Rudolf Mossbauer, where he explains the effect that he discovered and a bit about the history behind it.
Rudolph Mössbauer explaining the Mössbauer effect

Thank you!! So if am correct the frequency change present due to gaseous atom moving is only due to Doppler effect and this frequency change happens only in solid is there a reason for that?

I'll edit it and include the answer for this question
